# ADD Command for Docker Toolbox on Mac

Tags: macos, docker

I have Docker Toolbox installed on my Mac, but I'm having issues adding a file to a container during build. I'm using the ADD command in the Dockerfile. I can't seem to add any local files. I understand that Docker Toolbox uses VirtualBox under the hood, but I am not sure how to get those files into the VM to build the container. Is there a way I can do it that allows me to keep a clean OS-agnostic Dockerfile without any absolute paths?

Here is my Dockerfile. It's built from the Node.js container with some additional dependencies.

```
FROM node:4.2.2

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libvips-dev libgsf-1-dev libkrb5-dev
RUN apt-get clean

ADD app/ /app
RUN cd /app && npm install --production
RUN npm install forever -g
```

Comment: Need more info, Can you paste your ```Dockerfile``` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Since docker will use a VirtualBox VM on Mac (with boot2docker or with docker-machine), it will use **VirtualBox Guest Additions**, which is there for the express purpose of using VirtualBox folder sharing.

Make sure to be in such a shared path, typically in `/Users/...`.

If `app/` is in `/Users/path/to/app`, then `ADD` should work.

You can mount [other paths with boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#virtualbox-guest-additions), but it can be [problematic with docker machine](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1826#issuecomment-146882054) (see [issue 13](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/13)).

Of course, for `ADD app ...` to work, you need to be in the parent folder of `app/`.
From [docker `ADD`](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add):

> The `<src>` path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot `ADD` `../something /something`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this does work, but only for my current directory. My Dockerfile and the files I wanted to add were not in the same directory. Moving the shell to the files I wanted, and then manually specifying the Dockerfile worked.

```
docker build -f my/other/Dockerfile .
```